# is that possible hide all * sign with css

Tags: php, css

I have a strange problem ,all `*` sign not show !!!, I disable all javascript but still problem exist, all disable all css and I see `*` sign, it is strange, is that possible hide all `*` in everywhere ( in div,in span,in textbox , in everywhere of page ) ? 
how can I found solution for this problem?

Comment: Can you please edit the question and provide the relevant code in the question itself? We should not need to click on some unknown link to understand the basics of a question.

Comment: You might try changing the font, perhaps there is no available character for the asterix in the font-family you're using.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario  my problem is not related to code, I dont know who worte this, I just debug it, I am part of team, my problem is about css and  it is only a sample

Comment: @zhilevan try using `&#042;` ascii code instead of `*`. To replace everywhere in your code. use `replace all` from your editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your font for your "*" :

```
<span style="font-family: Arial;">*</span> Your text
```

And to answer your question, it is not possible. Fr1tz is right, your font WeKant don't contain the * character.

Answer (score 0):

If you place `&#42` where you want the`*` to be it should appear correctly.
Use this webpage for all of the ASCII HTML numbers: http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Comment: no, it was because of my font-family , tnx for your attentions

Comment: Oh, well if you ever run into the issue of not being able to display a `-`, `_`, etc then use the above link and replace the sign with the code